# How do I filter Html table on default dropdown value on page laod in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

This is my Select

```
    <select class="viewcombobox" ng-model="search.view_nm">
        <option ng-repeat="tab in CompetRx | unique:'view_nm'" value="{{tab.view_nm}}">{{tab.view_nm}}</option>
    </select>
```

Dropdown value are Weekly & Monthly

This is my table

```
    <table>
    <tr> <th> Brand </th> </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="tab in CompetRx | filter:search.view_nm > 
    </table>
```

On intial page load how do I set Weekly as default value in Dropdown at same time it should filter the table accordingly

Immediate help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't initialised your search object.

```
$scope.CompetRx =[{view_nm: "Weekly"}, {view_nm: "Monthly"}]
$scope.search = {view_nm: "Weekly"}
```

I created small working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aM24poL3qJ3yKDlLkbpT?p=preview). Hope it will help.